# How would you skip Laravel Scout if enviroment is not production?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout

I have an app that I am writing with Laravel.  I am still fairly new with the framework and don't understand most of it. I am using Algolia as the search engine with Laravel's Scout.  In the models you add `use Searchable`, a trait, and the records are automatically passed to Algolia, which is cool.  I am trying to put a simple statement `if (App::environment('local'))" exit scout`, just so we are not sending our development data to Algolia.  Scout will also throw an exception if I run out of the hacker level of 10,000 records a Algolia.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your local .env add

```
SCOUT_DRIVER=null
```

In production add

```
SCOUT_DRIVER=algolia
```

In config/scout.php add

```
'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER', 'null')
```

Automatically it will be ignored in local but work in production. 
This is just a suggestion. Try to adapt it to your specific context.

Comment: Almost perfect!  just drop the "SCOUT_DRIVER=null" in the local .env.  Otherwise it fails when the driver is checked.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a Laravel search related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485513/laravel-search-with-multiple-keywords-against-multiple-columns-with-the-search ?

Answer (score 4):

On your local environment you can call [`YourModel::disableSearchSyncing()`](https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/master/src/Searchable.php#L154), which will prevent this model from pushing data to Algolia.

The reverse to this method is [`YourModel::enableSeachSyncing()`](https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/master/src/Searchable.php#L144), but the search is enabled by default, so usually there is no need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

create .env.testing file in the root of your project and simply set

```
SCOUT_DRIVER=null
```

it's described here [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing#the-env-testing-environment-file)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Laravel 5.3 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration):

1. Set the environment the in the `.env` file:

   ```
   APP_ENV=local
   ```
2. Determine the current environment:

   ```
   $environment = App::environment();
   ```
3. Check on `$environment` and return true:

   ```
   if (App::environment('local')) {
       // The environment is local
   }
   if (App::environment('local', 'staging')) {
       // The environment is either local OR staging...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

None of above solution works I suggest you to check in your `toSearchableArray()` method inside your `User` Model. If you try to set the `SCOUT_DRIVER=null` in local environment then you will face an error because your application tends to push to Algolia in any environment.

Try to do this instead:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    if (! app()->isLocal()) {
        return [
            'username' => $this->username,
            'age'      => (string) $this->age,
            // and so on ...
        ];
    }
}
```